# C/C++ in Eclipse, can I use a #define to set a breakpoint, but only when steping through code?

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, debugging, breakpoints

Years ago I had a little `#define` which I used in Borland C++ Builder. From memory, it was something *approximately* like

```
 #define BREAK_IF_DEBUGGING asm(0xA3);
```

or something like that. It relied on 0XA3 (or whatever it was) being the op code for the interrupt which Borland were using to trigger a breakpoint.

Can I do the same thing in Eclipse?  (I'll probably wrap it in a few `#idef ECLIPSE` and `#ifdef TESTING`)

What I hope to achieve here is that
- the code compiles away to nothing in the release version, of course.
- if I run by unit tests with Ctrl-F11 then I don't want a breakpint to be triggered (which it won't because of Ctrl-F11 being "Run")
- if I "Run with Debug" using F11) then if executions hits any use of the macro then it will stop at a breakpoint.

Why? Because I want to set & forget. Just put one of these in each error leg (or embed it in my `LOG_ERROR` macro).

Often when I choose my initial breakpoint, it is too late, so this macro says "I think I want to run to line X, but if execution passes through one of those error branches first, I'd like to stop there & sniff around".

Whether you like the idea or not, can you tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what about

```
#define BREAK_IF_DEBUGGING asm("int3");
```

*(the lack of space between int and 3 is intentional : int 3 being encoded differently from other interrupts, the gnu assembler mark this difference with this special syntax)*

Comment: That looks like it might be my answer, thanks. I will test it out & get back to you.

Comment: Please accept my apologies for taking so long to get back to you. You answer is spot on. here's my actual code...   

    #if TESTING==UNIT_TEST
    #define BREAK_IF_DEBUGGING   asm("int3");
    #else
    #if TESTING==SOFTWARE_INTEGRATION_TEST
    #define BREAK_IF_DEBUGGING   asm("int3");
    #else
    #define BREAK_IF_DEBUGGING   ;
    #endif
    #endif

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Windows function IsDebuggerPresent (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680345%28VS.85%29.aspx) to check whether a debugger is attached to your process or not.

If a debugger is attached, you can use the BreakPoint function to trigger a breakpoint.

Comment: +1, but not really generic - I develop cross-platform code.

(I suppose I can add an o/s check)

Comment: You could add a hidden command line option to replace the IsDebuggerPresent call.  Then you need to remember to add this option if you want to debug.
For the BreakPoint function you could use an assert that always goes off.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a unix OS, you can do something like:

```
raise(SIGTRAP);
```

Comment: RedMeat, +1, but not really generic - I develop cross-platform code. 

(I suppose I can add an o/s check)

Comment: @Mawg: x86-only isn't "cross-platform" either.

Answer (score 0):

How about

> ## define BREAK_IF_DEBUGGING assert(false);

Clearly, you can make better use of assert().

Comment: The problem with assert() is that it calls abort() which ends the process.